# attachment from cURL in phpMailer

Tags: php, curl, attachment, phpmailer

I'm trying to retrieve file from URL and attach it to mail created using phpMailer class. The main point is to not save file on the server's hard drive. File is retrieved from server using following request *serverURL*/index.php?action=download&id=2
The problem is I'm not able to retrieve file, I was able to get only header. Any suggestions will be great. Thanks!

Comment: How are you retrieving the file? Show us some code :)

Comment: By default cURL only returns header information. Check your options settings.

Comment: Below is the code I use to retrieve file

`$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
$mail->AddStringAttachment($result, $att['filename']);
curl_close($ch);`